# Blinking border of a View

Tags: android

I have a `View` and a border which i wanted to blink specific time. I tried to to make blink but the problem is whole view is blinking. i know its becource i mentioned `View` inside a `Linearlayout` which background set to a border stock.

Here is the code:

```
xml:
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp
        android:id="@+id/rect2"
        android:background="@drawable/cir"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="#14FFFFFF"
           android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/inrect2"
       />
    </LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
 //somecode
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             re2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rect2);
            myView2= findViewById(R.id.inrect2);

        ((GradientDrawable)re1.getBackground()).setStroke(1,Color.WHITE);
                    AlphaAnimation blinkanimation= new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
                    blinkanimation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
                    blinkanimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
                    blinkanimation.setRepeatCount(28); // Repeat animation infinitely
                    blinkanimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                    re1.startAnimation(blinkanimation);
```

`re1.startAnimation(blinkanimation)` seems start animating whole linear layout,Is there anyway i can make blink only borders?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of blinking the view, try blinking the outer linear layout, the view and linear layout should have padding between them in order to give a border like effect.

**[Edit]**

Try stacking the `View` on top of `LinearLayout` using a `FrameLayout`, the `LinearLayout` should be slightly large to simulate a border-like effect.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <Linearlayout  
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="20dp" 
    android:layout_height="20dp" 
 />

  <View
    android:layout_width="16dp" 
    android:layout_height="16dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#AA000000" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: edited code, Yes i have already padding and i can see outerline of the view in XML. problem is how can i be animate only Linearlayout but not view inside it?

Comment: I see, then stack the view on top of linearlayout using a framelayout and check if it works.

Comment: WOW.. You just had it!! Thanks mate! Working great